# Подключение шаблона в Ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

Есть Rails приложение, к которому нужно подключить шаблон [finesse](http://themeforest.net/item/finesse-responsive-business-html-template/full_screen_preview/3227147).

В application.css

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

в application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

в application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

В папке /stylesheets файлы:

```
/colors
application.css
flexslider.css
html5-reset.css
ie.css
jquery.fancybox.css
mediaelementplayer.css
polyglot-language-switcher.css
shortcodes.css
style.css
```

В папке /javascripts файлы:

```
application.js
custom.js
ddlevelsmenu.js
ie.js
jflickrfeed.min.js
jquery.cycle.all.js
jquery.easing.1.3.js
jquery.fancybox.pack.js
jquery.fitvids.js
jquery.flexslider-min.js
jquery.gmap.min.js
jquery.jcarousel.min.js
jquery.polyglot.language.switcher.js
jquery.quicksand.js
jquery.touchSwipe.min.js
jquery.tweet.js
jquery.ui.totop.min.js
jquery.validate.min.js
jquery-1.11.1.min.js
jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js
mediaelement-and-player.min.js
modernizr.custom.js
respond.min.js
responsive-tables.js
tinynav.min.js
```

Все ссылки на изображения в шаблоне имеют вид:

```
./../images/background-patterns/boxed/grid.png
```

Все файлы, которые шли вместе с шаблоном, были размещены по папкам в соответствии с архитектурой приложения, но дело в том, что при рендере страницы не работают JavaScript элементы (карусель и т.д.) и не подгружаются изображения. Как правильно подключать шаблоны в Rails приложениях?

Пример index.html.erb

```html
<body>
  <!-- begin container -->
  <div id="wrap">
    <!-- begin header -->
    <header id="header" class="container">
      <!-- begin header top -->
      <section id="header-top" class="clearfix">
        <!-- begin header left -->
        <div class="one-half">
          <h1 id="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" alt="Finesse"></a></h1>
          <p id="tagline">Responsive Business Theme</p>
        </div>
        <!-- end header left -->
          <!-- begin contact info -->
          <div class="contact-info">
            <p class="phone">(123) 456-7890</p>
            <p class="email"><a href="mailto:info@finesse.com">info@finesse.com</a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <!-- end contact info -->
        </div>
        <!-- end header right -->
      </section>
      <!-- end header top -->

      <!-- begin navigation bar -->
      <section id="navbar" class="clearfix">
        <!-- begin navigation -->
        <nav id="nav">
          <ul id="navlist" class="clearfix">
            <li class="current"><a href="index.html" data-rel="submenu1">Home</a>
              <ul id="submenu1" class="ddsubmenustyle">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home Version 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="index-2.html">Home Version 2</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="about-us.html" data-rel="submenu2">Templates</a>
              <ul id="submenu2" class="ddsubmenustyle">
                <li><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="sitemap.html">Sitemap</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="404-error-page.html">404 Error Page</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="search-results.html">Search Results</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="full-width-page.html">Full Width Page</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="page-right-sidebar.html">Page with Right Sidebar</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="page-left-sidebar.html">Page with Left Sidebar</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Multi-Level Drop-Down</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Drop-Down Example</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Multi-Level Drop-Down</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Drop-Down Example</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drop-Down Example</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drop-Down Example</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Drop-Down Example</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="elements.html" data-rel="submenu3">Features</a>
              <ul id="submenu3" class="ddsubmenustyle">
                <li><a href="elements.html">Elements</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="grid-columns.html">Grid Columns</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="pricing-tables.html">Pricing Tables</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="images.html">Images</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="video.html">Video</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="portfolio.html" data-rel="submenu4">Portfolio</a>
              <ul id="submenu4" class="ddsubmenustyle">
                <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="portfolio-item-slider.html">Portfolio Item &ndash; Slider</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="portfolio-item-image.html">Portfolio Item &ndash; Image</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="portfolio-item-embedded-video.html">Portfolio Item &ndash; Embedded Video</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="portfolio-item-self-hosted-video.html">Portfolio Item &ndash; Self-Hosted Video</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="blog.html" data-rel="submenu5">Blog</a>
              <ul id="submenu5" class="ddsubmenustyle">
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="blog-post.html">Blog Post</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- end navigation -->

        <!-- begin search form -->
        <form id="search-form" action="search.php" method="get">
          <input id="s" type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search &hellip;" style="display: none;">
          <input id="search-submit" type="submit" name="search-submit" value="Search">
        </form>
        <!-- end search form -->
      </section>
      <!-- end navigation bar -->

    </header>
    <!-- end header -->

    <!-- begin content -->
    <section id="content" class="container clearfix">
      <!-- begin slider -->
      <section id="slider-home">
        <div class="flex-container">
          <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
              <li>
                <img src="./../images/slider/slides/living-white-940x350.png" alt="White Living Room">
                <div class="flex-caption">
                  <h2>Responsive Layout</h2>
                  <p>You can describe your slides using captions. This is an example of a caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.</p>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <img src="./../images/slider/slides/villa-940x350.png" alt="Villa">
                <div class="flex-caption">
                  <h2>HTML5 &amp; CSS3 Code</h2>
                  <p>You can describe your slides using captions. This is an example of a caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.</p>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <img src="./../images/slider/slides/building-940x350.png" alt="Building">
                <div class="flex-caption">
                  <h2>Clean Design</h2>
                  <p>You can describe your slides using captions. This is an example of a caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.</p>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <img src="./../images/slider/slides/living-brown-940x350.png" alt="Brown Living Room">
                <div class="flex-caption">
                  <h2>Touch Enabled</h2>
                  <p>You can describe your slides using captions. This is an example of a caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.</p>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <img src="./../images/slider/slides/dining-brown-940x350.png" alt="Brown Dining Room">
                <div class="flex-caption">
                  <h2>Easy to Customize</h2>
                  <p>You can describe your slides using captions. This is an example of a caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.</p>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- end slider -->

      <!-- begin infobox -->
      <section>
        <div class="infobox">
          <div class="infobox-inner">
            <a class="button large" href="http://themeforest.net/user/ixtendo/portfolio">Learn More</a>
            <div class="with-button">
              <h2>Responsive Business &amp; Portfolio Theme with a Refreshingly Clean Design</h2>
              <p>Carefully handcrafted using the latest technologies, Finesse features a clean design, as well as extended functionality that will come in very handy. Take a tour and discover its features!</p>
            </div>
            <a class="button large mobile-button" href="http://themeforest.net/user/ixtendo/portfolio">Learn More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- end infobox -->

      <!-- begin services -->
      <section>
        <h2>Our Services <span class="more">&ndash; <a href="services.html">View All Services &raquo;</a></span></h2>

        <!-- begin iconbox carousel -->
        <ul class="iconbox-carousel">
          <li>
            <div class="iconbox computer">
              <h4><a href="services.html#responsive-layouts"><span class="iconbox-icon"></span>Responsive Layouts</a></h4>
              <p>Layouts that scale gracefully across varying screen sizes.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="iconbox mouse">
              <h4><a href="services.html#html5-css3-code"><span class="iconbox-icon"></span>HTML5 &amp; CSS3 Code</a></h4>
              <p>Standards-compliant and cross-browser HTML/CSS code.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="iconbox applications">
              <h4><a href="services.html#clean-design"><span class="iconbox-icon"></span>Clean Design</a></h4>
              <p>Professional, clutter-free and aesthetically simple design.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
           
            <div class="iconbox chemical">
              <h4><a href="services.html#it-solutions"><span class="iconbox-icon"></span>IT Solutions</a></h4>
              <p>Connecting technology to your business needs.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- end iconbox carousel -->
      </section>
      <!-- end services -->

      <!-- begin selected projects -->
      <section>
        <h2>Selected Projects <span class="more">&ndash; <a href="portfolio.html">View All Projects &raquo;</a></span></h2>

        <!-- begin project carousel -->
        <ul class="project-carousel">
          <li class="entry">
            <div class="entry-image">
              <a class="fancybox" href="./../images/entries/full-size/dining-white.jpg" title="Project Title"><span class="overlay zoom"></span><img src="images/entries/220x130/dining-white-220x130.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <h4 class="entry-title"><a href="portfolio-item-image.html">White Dining Room</a></h4>
            <div class="entry-content">
              <p>Image project with lightbox.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="entry">
            <div class="entry-image">
              <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery-living-large-windows" href="./../images/entries/full-size/living-large-windows.jpg" title="Project Title"><span class="overlay zoom"></span><img src="images/entries/220x130/living-large-windows-220x130.png" alt=""></a>
              <a class="fancybox invisible" data-fancybox-group="gallery-living-large-windows" href="./../images/entries/full-size/living-brown.jpg" title="Project Title"><span class="overlay zoom"></span><img src="images/entries/220x130/living-brown-220x130.png" alt=""></a>
              <a class="fancybox invisible" data-fancybox-group="gallery-living-large-windows" href="./../images/entries/full-size/dining-and-living-cream.jpg" title="Project Title"><span class="overlay zoom"></span><img src="images/entries/220x130/dining-and-living-cream-220x130.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <h4 class="entry-title"><a href="portfolio-item-image.html">Living with Large Windows</a></h4>
            <div class="entry-content">
              <p>Gallery project with lightbox.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="entry">
            <div class="entry-slider">
              <ul>
                <li><a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery-living-brown" href="./../images/entries/full-size/living-brown.jpg" title="Project Title"><span class="overlay zoom"></span><img src="images/entries/220x130/living-brown-220x130.png" alt=""></a>
                </li>
                <li style="display: none;"><a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery-living-brown" href="./../images/entries/full-size/dining-and-living-cream.jpg" title="Project Title"><span class="overlay zoom"></span><img src="images/entries/220x130/dining-and-living-cream-220x130.png" alt=""></a>
                </li>
                <li style="display: none;"><a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery-living-brown" href="./../images/entries/full-size/living-white.jpg" title="Project Title"><span class="overlay zoom"></span><img src="images/entries/220x130/living-white-220x130.png" alt=""></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <h4 class="entry-title"><a href="portfolio-item-slider.html">Brown Living Room</a></h4>
            <div class="entry-content">
              <p>Gallery project with slider and lightbox.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="entry">
            <div class="entry-video">
              <video width="220" height="130" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" poster="images/entries/220x130/dining-and-living-cream-220x130.png" controls preload="none">
                <!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->
                <source type="video/mp4" src="./../media/echo-hereweare.mp4" />
                <!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->
                <source type="video/webm" src="./../media/echo-hereweare.webm" />
                <!-- Ogg/Vorbis for older Firefox and Opera versions -->
                <source type="video/ogg" src="./../media/echo-hereweare.ogv" />
                <!-- Optional: Add subtitles for each language -->
                <track kind="subtitles" src="./../media/mediaelement.srt" srclang="en" />
                <!-- Optional: Add chapters -->
                <track kind="chapters" src="#" srclang="en" />
                <!-- Flash fallback for non-HTML5 browsers without JavaScript -->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="./flashmediaelement.swf">
                  <param name="movie" value="./flashmediaelement.swf" />
                  <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&amp;file=media/echo-hereweare.mp4" />
                  <!-- Image as a last resort -->
                  <img src="./entries/220x130/dining-and-living-cream-220x130.png" title="No video playback capabilities" alt="" />
                </object>
              </video>
            </div>
            <h4 class="entry-title"><a href="portfolio-item-self-hosted-video.html">Self-Hosted Video Project</a></h4>
            <div class="entry-content">
              <p>Self-hosted video project.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <!-- begin row 2 -->
          <li class="entry">
            <div class="entry-image">
              <a class="fancybox" href="./../images/entries/full-size/living-white.jpg" title="Project Title"><span class="overlay zoom"></span><img src="images/entries/220x130/living-white-220x130.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <h4 class="entry-title"><a href="portfolio-item-image.html">White Living Room</a></h4>
            <div class="entry-content">
              <p>Image project with lightbox.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="entry">
            <div class="entry-image">
              <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery-study" href="./../images/entries/full-size/study.jpg" title="Project Title"><span class="overlay zoom"></span><img src="images/entries/220x130/study-220x130.png" alt=""></a>
              <a class="fancybox invisible" data-fancybox-group="gallery-study" href="./../images/entries/full-size/dining-white2.jpg" title="Project Title"><span class="overlay zoom"></span><img src="images/entries/220x130/dining-white2-220x130.png" alt=""></a>
              <a class="fancybox invisible" data-fancybox-group="gallery-study" href="./../images/entries/full-size/dining-brown.jpg" title="Project Title"><span class="overlay zoom"></span><img src="images/entries/220x130/dining-brown-220x130.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <h4 class="entry-title"><a href="portfolio-item-image.html">Study</a></h4>
            <div class="entry-content">
              <p>Gallery project with lightbox.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="entry">
            <h4 class="entry-title"><a href="portfolio-item-slider.html">White Dining Room 2</a></h4>
            <div class="entry-content">
              <p>Gallery project with slider and lightbox.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="entry">
            <div class="entry-video">
              <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/11624173?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="220" height="110" allowFullScreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <h4 class="entry-title"><a href="portfolio-item-embedded-video.html">Arhitectural Film &ndash; Interior</a></h4>
            <div class="entry-content">
              <p>Embedded video project.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- end project carousel -->
      </section>
      <!-- end selected projects -->

      <!-- begin latest posts -->
      <section>
        <h2>Latest Posts <span class="more">&ndash; <a href="blog.html">View All Posts &raquo;</a></span></h2>

        <!-- begin post carousel -->
        <ul class="post-carousel">
          <li class="entry">
            <div class="entry-image">
              <a href="blog-post.html" title="Post Title"><span class="overlay link"></span><img src="./../images/entries/220x130/living-white-220x130.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-meta">
              <a href="blog-post.html" class="post-format-wrap" title="Permalink to How to Make Innovative Ideas Happen"><span class="post-format standard">Permalink</span></a>
              <span>Mar 10, 2012</span>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-body">
              <h4 class="entry-title"><a href="blog-post.html">How to Make Innovative Ideas Happen</a></h4>
              <div class="entry-content">
                <p>This is a standard post format. Here you can have a standard blog post &hellip;</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
            <div class="entry-meta">
              <a href="blog-post.html" class="post-format-wrap" title="Permalink to The Elements of the Mobile User Experience"><span class="post-format video">Permalink</span></a>
              <span>Mar 10, 2012</span>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-body">
              <h4 class="entry-title"><a href="blog-post.html">The Elements of the Mobile User Experience</a></h4>
              <div class="entry-content">
                <p>This is a video post format. Here you can have a video blog post &hellip;</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <!-- begin row 2 -->
          <li class="entry">
            <div class="entry-audio">
              <audio width="220" style="width: 100%;" src="./../media/AirReview-Landmarks-02-ChasingCorporate.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls preload="none"></audio>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-meta">
              <a href="blog-post.html" class="post-format-wrap" title="Permalink to How To Design A Mobile Game With HTML5"><span class="post-format audio">Permalink</span></a>
              <span>Mar 10, 2012</span>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-body">
              <h4 class="entry-title"><a href="blog-post.html">How To Design A Mobile Game With HTML5</a></h4>
              <div class="entry-content">
                <p>This is an audio post format. Here you can have an audio blog post &hellip;</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="entry">
            <div class="entry-meta">
              <a href="blog-post.html" class="post-format-wrap" title="Permalink to Premium Templates and Themes!"><span class="post-format link">Permalink</span></a>
              <span>Mar 10, 2012</span>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="entry">
            <div class="entry-meta">
              <a href="blog-post.html" class="post-format-wrap" title="Permalink to the Quote Post"><span class="post-format quote">Permalink</span></a>
              <span>Mar 10, 2012</span>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-body">
              <div class="entry-content">
                <blockquote class="simple">
                  <div class="quote-content">
                    <p>This is a quote post format. Here you can have a quote blog post &hellip;</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="quote-meta">&mdash; Quote Author</div>
                </blockquote>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="entry">
            <div class="entry-meta">
              <a href="blog-post.html" class="post-format-wrap" title="Permalink to the Aside Post"><span class="post-format aside">Permalink</span></a>
              <span>Mar 10, 2012</span>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-body">
              <div class="entry-content">
                <p>This is an aside post format. Here you can have an aside blog post &hellip;</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- end post carousel -->
      </section>
      <!-- end latest posts -->

      <!-- begin newsletter -->
      <section class="one-half">
        <h2>Newsletter Subscription</h2>
        <div id="newsletter-wrap">
          <p>Subscribe to our email newsletter for useful tips and valuable resources sent out every second Monday.</p>
          <div class="notification-box notification-box-success" style="display: none;">
            <p>You have successfully subscribed to our newsletter. Look for the confirmation email.</p>
            <a href="#" class="notification-close notification-close-success">x</a>
          </div>

          <div class="notification-box notification-box-error" style="display: none;">
            <p>Your email address couldn't be subscribed because a server error occurred. Please try again later.</p>
            <a href="#" class="notification-close notification-close-error">x</a>
          </div>
          <form id="newsletter-form" class="content-form clearfix" action="#" method="post">
            <input id="subscribe" class="button" type="submit" name="subscribe" value="Subscribe">
            <input id="newsletter" type="email" name="newsletter" placeholder="Enter your email address here &hellip;" class="required">
          </form>
          <p class="tip"><span class="note">&#42;</span> Check your spam folder if the mail does not arrive.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- end newsletter -->

      <!-- begin testimonials -->
      <section class="one-half column-last">
        <h2>Testimonials <span class="more">&ndash; <a href="testimonials.html">View All Testimonials &raquo;</a></span></h2>

        <!-- begin testimonial carousel -->
        <ul class="testimonial-carousel">
          <li>
            <blockquote class="speech-bubble">
              <div class="quote-content">
                <p>Great theme! Very intuitive, clean code, very well-organized documentation &ndash; I would highly recommend getting this theme; it’s ideal for further customization!</p>
                <span class="quote-arrow"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="quote-meta">Harry Jones, Web Designer
                <br>
                <span class="grey-text">CreativeBrains</span>
              </div>
            </blockquote>
          </li>
          <li>
            <blockquote class="speech-bubble">
              <div class="quote-content">
                <p>I would rate the template 5 out of 5 and here's why: it has a clean and straightforward look that will work for a variety of target audiences, which is important when you build for ROI.</p>
                <span class="quote-arrow"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="quote-meta">Andrew Williams, Art Director
                <br>
                <span class="grey-text">SmartBiz</span>
              </div>
            </blockquote>
          </li>
          <li>
            <blockquote class="speech-bubble">
              <div class="quote-content">
                <p>The template is really intuitive to customize and, the few instances where I needed help, you were right there to assist, in a timely manner, I might add. Well done, keep up the great work!</p>
                <span class="quote-arrow"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="quote-meta">Larry Thompson, Web Developer
                <br>
                <span class="grey-text">BitVenture</span>
              </div>
            </blockquote>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- end testimonial carousel -->
      </section>
      <!-- end testimonials -->
    </section>
    <!-- end content -->
  </div>
  <!-- end container -->
</body>
```

Comment: Не имеет смысла добавлять слова _Ruby on rails_ в заголовок вопроса, так как присутствует метка _ruby-on-rails_.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно заменить все ссылки на изображения в CSS и JS файлах с использованием [assets pepeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

1. Переименуйте CSS файлы шаблона в `имя.css.erb`
2. Там, где есть ссылки на картинки, поменяйте по аналогии с примером:

   ```
   .class { background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'image.png' %>) }
   ```